# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having a problem with my music bot. It doesn't return any errors, but when I run the "gg!join" command in the text chat, it gives me an error "`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'!`" in the console.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Meu Computador\Documents\GitHub\GrooveGriot\main.py", line 16, in join 
    channel = message.message.author.voice.voice_channel
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
2023-07-08 02:40:16 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1221, in _call
    command, options = self._get_app_command_options(data)
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1125, in _get_app_command_options
    raise CommandNotFound(name, parents)
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'say' not found
```

I apologize for my amateurism, it's my first post here, and I'm kind of in a hurry.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import decouple as dec

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='gg!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ONLINE!')

@bot.command(name="join")
async def join(message):
    channel = message.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
    
# fim da linha de comandos

#configurações de token seguro
TOKEN = dec.config("key")
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please change `message` param to `ctx` which means context. Since you use a command not a `on_message` event, so there is no message param. And this can cause confusion and extremely lower readability. Therefore, you should have something like this

```py
@bot.command(name='join')
async def join(ctx: commands.Context):
  channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
  await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

And then, the major problem causes the error is `ctx.message.author.voice` will  give you a `VoiceState` and `VoiceState` only has `channel` attribute other than `voice_channel`. [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState)
Also, You need to check member voicestate before you get their voice channel because they might not be in the voice channel, in this case, their `VoiceState` is `None`. And `VoiceState.channel` will obviously give your a `NoneType` error. 
And there is no such method called `join_voice_channel` for `discord.ext.commands.Bot`. [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceClient)
One more thing, you can access member `VoiceState` by `ctx.author.voice`, which is simpler.
So, this should be something like,

```py
@bot.command(name='join')
async def join(ctx: commands.Context):
  if ctx.author.voice:  # check if member has VoiceState
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, I took the opportunity to add a function to be performed if the user is not connected in a voice channel.